# how to know whether the command executed properly or not with pxssh

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I am trying to automate ssh. I want to execute a command inside ssh and want to know whether the command executed properly or not. I am using the `pxssh` module to achieve this. I am able to execute the command but not able to get the status using `$` ?

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pxssh

host='syslog.plivo.com'
user='root'
command = 'abc'

def connect(hostname,username):
    try:
        s = pxssh.pxssh()
        s.login(hostname,username)
        return s
    except Exception, e:
        print " Error connection: "+str(e)

def send_command(ssh_session,command):
    ssh_session.sendline(command)
    #ssh_session.sendline("$?")
    #ssh_session.prompt()
    #print ssh_session.before

def main():
    session=connect(host,user)
    send_command(session,command)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Did you try `ssh_session.sendline("echo $?")` ?

Comment: i tried ssh_session.sendline("echo \"$?\"") still not working